# Header repeating all pages in python docx

Tags: python, docx

I want to make my document header only at first page, but it repeating every pages

here's the code

```
section = doc.sections[0]  # Create a section
sec_header = section.header   # Create header 
header_tp = sec_header.add_paragraph()  # Add a paragraph in the header, you can add any anything in the paragraph
header_run = header_tp.add_run()   # Add a run in the paragraph. In the run you can set the values 
header_run.add_picture(logo_path, width=Inches(1.24), height=Inches(0.30))  # Add a picture and set width.
rml_header = "\t\t\t\t\t       Project completion report"
header_run.add_text(rml_header)
header_run.bold = True        
header_run.add_text("\n_____________________________________________________________")
header_run.font.size =  Pt(14)
```

Can anyone help me by what changes should i make